# How to fix this sql with LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the follow two mysql tables:

```
mysql> desc subscriptions;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_user    | int(6)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_package | int(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expiry     | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip         | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount     | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| processed  | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> desc packages;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_panel | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price    | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| period   | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| days     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| visible  | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| payment  | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm using the follow query to retrive all the packages and the relative USER expirations date (of the specific package).

```
SELECT packages.id, packages.name, packages.price, packages.period, packages.days, MAX(subscriptions.expiry) as expiry
FROM packages LEFT JOIN subscriptions
ON subscriptions.id_package = packages.id AND subscriptions.processed = 1 AND subscriptions.id_user = 1
WHERE packages.visible = 1
GROUP BY subscriptions.id_user
ORDER BY packages.id_panel
```

My problem is that if there is not the subscription of a specific package the query does not show the package.

I MUST show all the page and....IF the user has a subscription  check the MAX expiry date (becase i track all the subscrions the user made).

How can i show all the packages and the relative user expiration dates? (and if there is no subscription of a package show NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're grouping by `subscriptions.id_user`, yet you select all your non_aggregates from the `packages` table.  Are you sure that you're grouping by the correct field?

It looks like it should be `packages.id`...

Comment: @Dail - Great, does your query work now with the different field in the GROUP BY? :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy... just move the `packages.visible = 1` condition into the `ON` clause!

```
SELECT packages.id, packages.name, packages.price, packages.period, packages.days, MAX(subscriptions.expiry) as expiry
FROM packages
LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.id_package = packages.id
    AND subscriptions.processed = 1
    AND subscriptions.id_user = 1
    AND packages.visible = 1
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY packages.id_panel
```

This approach is the *only* way to get conditions into a `LEFT JOIN`, and a great trick to remember.

Note: Your group by list was incorrect too

Comment: I think that this is incorrect.  As the packages table is on the left side of the join, having `packages.visible` reference in the where clause is not a problem.  Also, the suggested SQL now shows all packages, even if they're not visible, but just doesn't join the subscription to non-visible packages.  *[I think it's just the GROUP BY that was wrong.  And as it's MySQL, you only need to GROUP BY the unique identifier, not every field in the packages table.]*